# Wicket issue field value never used

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wicket

Very new to Wicket but have very basic Java. I am not understanding how "result" is not been used as I have used it in an AjaxButton function

The quickfix says to provide a getter and setter, which I did (have removed now) but still nothing happened when I click the OK button

CalcPage.java:

```
public class CalcPage extends WebPage{
    private int num;
    private int result; // error:The value of the field CalcPage.result is not used
    private Label r;

    public CalcPage() {
        Form<Void> f = new Form<Void>("f");
        add(f);
        f.add(new TextField<Integer>("num", new PropertyModel<Integer>(this, "num")));
        AjaxButton ok = new AjaxButton("ok") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                result = 2 * num;
                target.add(r);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {

            }
        };
        f.add(ok);
        r = new Label("r", new PropertyModel<Integer>(this, "result"));
        add(r);
    }
}
```

CalcPage.html

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Apache Wicket Quickstart</title>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:regular,bold' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form wicket:id="f">
            <input type="text" wicket:id="num"/>
            <input type="submit" value="OK" wicket:id="ok"/>
        </form>
        Result: <span wicket:id="r"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hoping (according to book Enjoying web development with Wicket) to double the input but when I click on OK and nothing happens.

Also in code I am getting a compile error with @Override, once this is removed I can compile and load webpage. Are they related??

Wicket Ajax Debug window info:
INFO: focus removed from

INFO: focus set on

INFO: focus removed from

INFO: focus set on wicketDebugLink

INFO: focus removed from wicketDebugLink

INFO: focus set on ok2

INFO: Received ajax response (69 characters)

INFO:

INFO: Response processed successfully.

INFO: refocus last focused component not needed/allowed

ETA I changed from private  to public and that error is gone but clicking ok still doesn't work and new error has come:
The method onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget, Form) from the type new AjaxButton(){} is never used locally

Comment: Just to make sure: Can you check if the import for the `AjaxButton` you are using is `org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton`?

Comment: Imports is correct:

import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Version 8 of wicket  doesn't have the "form" parameter so it can be deleted:

new code

```
AjaxButton ok = new AjaxButton("ok") {

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            result= 2*num;
            target.add(r);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `r.setOutputMarkupId(true)` if you want to update a Component via Ajax.

1) if javac (or your IDE) says that `@Override` does not override anything then most probably you have a typo somewhere and you need to fix it, i.e. to properly override the method from super

2) never leave `#onError()` empty. As a minimum add some basic logging in it to notify you that there is a validation error. Maybe `#onSubmit()` is not called at all. The best would be to have a FeedbackPanel in the page and you should update it in `#onError()` - `target.add(feedbackPanel)`

3) Check the browser's Dev tools Console for JavaScript errors. I'd expect Wicket complaining that it cannot find an HTML element with id `rXY` (where `XY` is a number) because of the missing `r.setOutputMarkupId(true)`

Comment: 1. I can't seem to find a typo, I have been through it letter by letter. Maybe it was printed in book with an error. Get another pair of eyes to check

2. next section has addition for a feedback panel, I have added it now and both the num *2 and the feedback panel are not giving me any response. It says in code both these methods not used locally

3. I forgot to add the r.setOutputMarkupId(true), but code for button still not working and there are no error in console. Infact Ajax is adding the new <span> but with the number as 0

Comment: Is `num` properly set to the value you enter in the input box ? Put a breakpoint in #onSubmit() and see what is its value

Comment: It never reaches this point and says it is never used locally. I set num to 5 and it still said 5 at the end and on webpage said "Result 0" so int result is not updated or used according to warning in Eclipse

Comment: If `onSubmit()` is not called then `onError()` must be called. Put breakpoints or logging in both of them and see which one is called.

Comment: Otherwise please create a mini project in GitHub/GitLab/BitBucket/... and we will take a look.